# Enterprise Architect using Java API, How to read interaction operator information from Sequence diagram?

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I was trying to use java API of enterprise Architect to read sequence diagram data, where I got stuck with reading interaction operator(type in diagram) from a combined fragment of the interaction fragment. Please refer the diagram below,

[image: Sequence Diagram With Interaction Operator in Combined Fragment]

I tried printing all the methods in the Element object. But I didn't get any information, expect this,

```
  Element ele = repo.GetElementByID(myDiagramObjects.GetElementID());
  System.out.println("Partitions Count: " + ele.GetPartitions().GetCount());
    for (Partition par : ele.GetPartitions()) {
      System.out.println("Par Name: " + par.GetName());
      System.out.println("Par Note: " + par.GetNote());
      System.out.println("Par Operator: " + par.GetOperator());
      System.out.println("Par Size: " + par.GetSize());
    }
  Output:
      Partitions Count: 1
      Par Name: testcondition
      Par Note: 
      Par Operator:
      Par Size: 47
```

If the name(refer diagram) is empty then,

Output:
    Partitions Count: 0

**Required Information,**

Need to read/print 'Type'(as per diagram) also called Interaction operator.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you need, and what is not working. I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: I have to read the 'Type'(first field) from the Combined Fragment(popup in the image) using java API

Comment: Please update the question with any clarifications. That info is probably stored somewhere in the EA.`Element`, not in the `Partition`

Comment: I guess that is what I have mentioned in the question, from Element object I was not able to retrieve the value. Can you clarify me from which method in Element can we get that value. I have checked with the all possible methods in the Element, But I am failed to read.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I would guess it would be hidden in subtype or MiscData or something similar. Best way to figure it out is to look in the database.

Comment: Thanks @Greet Bellekens. it is there in the subtype as integer representing each string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ele.GetSubtype()`

returns integer value which is an indexing for the drop down values.
 EX:

```
alt = 0
opt = 1
break = 2
.
.
```